# Convert custom date format (GMT-08-2021.08.31-18.29.05) to epoch time

Tags: bash, date, timezone

I have a date string that is supplied in the following format:

```
Timezone-Year.Month.Day-Hour.Minute.Second
GMT-08-2021.08.31-18.29.05
```

and I need to figure out how to get the date command to recognize it so I can convert it to epoch time.  This will be done in a bash script in case that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the timezone is always in the format `GMT-nn`, something like this could work to shuffle the fields around for the GNU version of `date` and `date -d`:

```
a="GMT-08-2021.08.31-18.29.05"
b=$(echo "$a" | sed -E -e 's/GMT([-+][0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/\2-\3-\4 \5:\6:\7 \100/')
date -u -d "$b"
```

That's basically just a bunch of capture groups (`(...)`) and putting them back in the right order (`\2` for the second group, etc.).

With that example value, `b` would contain `2021-08-31 18:29:05 -0800`, and I get `Wed Sep  1 02:29:05 UTC 2021` from `date`.

For other versions of `date`, you'd need some other output format.